# Retrieve List from firebase using Ionic 3

Tags: firebase, ionic3

I am trying to get back the information I have stored in a list on firebase.

In my home.ts file I scan in data from a barcode like this:

```
async scanBarcode(){ 

const results = await this.barcode.scan(); 
this.resultsUI = await this.barcode.scan(); 
console.log(results); 
}
```

Then I store that data in a list on firebase like this :

```
async storeBarcode(){ 

this.db.list('barcode').push(this.resultsUI);

let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Bar code stored',
  buttons: ['OK']
});
alert.present();
}
```

How can I retrieve this data back? I'm lost.

I've been trying this but no luck

```
this.db.database.ref('/barcode/').on('value', resp => {
  console.log(resp)
  this.dbBarcode = (resp);
});
```

Then in my home.html Im displaying the results like this:

```
<div *ngIf="dbBarcode">
<p>From Databse</p>
<p>Database code :{{dbBarcode.text}}</p>
```

Still not getting the data I want back though

New Code!!!

in app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',

 template: `
 <ul>
   <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">
   {{ item | json }}
   </li>
 </ul>
`,
})
 export class MyApp {
 rootPage:any = HomePage;
 items: Observable<any[]>;

 constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: 
  SplashScreen, db: AngularFireDatabase) {
  platform.ready().then(() => {
  // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
  // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
  statusBar.styleDefault();
  splashScreen.hide();

  this.items=db.list('barcode').valueChanges();
  });
 }
}
```

And in home.ts I have a button to click when I want the database contents to be returned

async getBarcode(){

```
this.itemsRef = this.db.list('barcode');
this.itemsRef.snapshotChanges(['child_added'])
 .subscribe(actions => {
   actions.forEach(action => {
   console.log(action.text);
   this.dbBarcode = (action.text);
 });
});
}
```

Comment: Are you using angularfire wrapper or firebase?

Comment: Im using Firebase. Imported like this :  import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

Comment: So since you are using angularfire - did you follow their documentation? Its pretty good. Check it out and let me know what is confusing you there

Comment: Yeah I've been looking at the docs. I presume you are talking about these [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) docs? I'm not sure if I am even looking in the correct place to be honest.

Comment: Yep wrong docs;) i will share the link u need

Comment: Check this one: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks. I have the data returning now alright but I it returns over every thing in the app. I'm guessing this is because I have it in app.component.ts and it runs when the app starts? Do you know a way I can only get it to run when I have the button clicked? I'll add my new code above

Comment: So which component your button should be in? Normally then you need to have your retrieve data method declared after “constructor” (not inside) and not within lifecycle methods (like ionViewDidLoad).

Comment: Once you have your method just put (click)=“yourMethod” in the button